# Apache Spark on Amazon EC2 PYTHONPATH trouble

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I need to run Apace Spark script on Amazon EC2. Script uses such libs, as numpy, pandas etc. The trouble is that I have numpy installed in 
`/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`, and this folder isn't in PYTHONPATH by default. So when I `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`, usual python detects it (`import numpy` causes no problems), but when I'm trying to import it in pyspark shell - it shows:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> exit()
```

is there any solution how to change pyspark's PYTHONPATH?

Comment: +1 on Joe's answer, I will refrain from a -1 on your question but it would be nice to know if this worked, to improve SO. Also, I can't edit just one character but it's "Apache" for Google not "Apace" haha :) This question shows very high in Google's search results, would help if you either delete it or complete it please?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```

in $SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-env.sh?

Comment: Ditto on this answer would be nice if OP would have responded, surely this was the problem and the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

[Joe Young's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31825640/3255525) is good if you want to set the path "permanently." If you want to set it on a per job basis, [Continuum](https://www.continuum.io/) (Anaconda folks) has this page about setting your PYTHONPATH job by job on the command line:

https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/using-anaconda-pyspark-distributed-language-processing-hadoop-cluster

For example (written for a Cloudera install substitute your Spark location):

**Configuring the spark-submit command with your Hadoop Cluster**

To use Python from Anaconda along with PySpark, you can set the PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable on a per-job basis along with the spark-submit command. If you’re using the Anaconda parcel for CDH, you can run a PySpark script (e.g., spark-job.py) using the following command:

`$ PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python spark-submit spark-job.py`

Comment: Looking at this more closely, I think Cloudera has a typo? Or this is an an interesting bit of a way to form a command. I would normally  enter  `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python` and `spark-submit spark-job.py ` on two lines, or separated by a `;`. But it works! Been using UNIX/Linux 20 years, learn something new every day! I tried `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python spark-submit spark-job.py ls -l` and it works.